# How to control Exoplayer inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, android-nestedscrollview

I have added exoplayer in recycler view which is inside the nested scroll view. the player is initialized.but I am facing some issues with that.

1. Whenever I m changing the fragment or scroll to bottom(nested scroll) video keeps playing in the background.
2. When I change the activity and came back to the same all videos start playing automatically.

Here is the main layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/swipe"
      android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragment.ForYou">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
  </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is sublayout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/backgroundgraident"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                android:id="@+id/video_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_250sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

                android:background="#000000"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:bar_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
                app:use_controller="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code

```
 private void initializePlayer(MyviewHolder hol , int pos) {

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context);

        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource( mediaUri );

        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
        player.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);

        player.setVideoScalingMode( C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
        playerView.setControlDispatcher( new MyDefaultControlDispatcher() );

        playerView.setPlayer(player);

}

private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
            new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, "exoplayer-codelab");
    return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(uri);
}

 public void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {

            if(player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();
            }

            playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            playbackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
            currentWindow = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your java code

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Hi can"t comment cause my rep is too low. I think a [Recycler listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.RecyclerListener) will help with 
the view scrolled off screen continuing to play, since you will be able to get the player 
when the holder recycles. With the changing fragment I don't really understand the question.

Comment: Also confused as to why you have a RecylerView in a Scrollview? Recycler view scrolls by default

Comment: I have a similar issue.
@Alexander I have a recycler view on my main screen with just the 3 last posts in my blog, I set the RV height to wrap_content so it doesn't scroll. So no need for the recyclerView to also scroll, the entire screen already scrolls. under the recyclerView there's a button which takes you to the screen for all the posts. 
Issue is, if recyclerView is not scrolling, how can i stop the views inside from playing media when scrolling the whole screen???

Comment: @Avramo I think the easiest option will be to not use a RecyclerView. The whole point of RecyclerView is for if you have large data sets so that that you don't end up with lists that are thousands of items long. Since you are only showing three items and it sounds like they won't need to scroll anyway why not just use a LinearLayout rather? Then by what you say I assume you have a ScrollView or something for scrolling the screen so then just use the height of the LinearLayout and compare it with the ScrollViews scroll position using an OnScrollListener. Maybe this will work

Comment: Hey, @Alexander Robinson The 3 latest posts are on the main screen, but on the Posts screen I show all the posts, and there I really need the RecyclerView. Since I use it in 2 places I thought it's easier to only code it once.

Comment: @Avramo Cool that makes sense. Then I suggest using the height of the RecyclerView and comparing it to the scroll position of your ScrollView. If the scroll position is greater than the height of the RV those posts will be off screen and you can safely stop playing the media. You can get even more refined control by comparing the height of individual children in the RV to your scroll position. In my mind at least this will work XD

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, I'll try that.   
Seems a bit tricky though since the posts' height are dynamic based on their content, length of post etc. and the height of the main screen is also dynamic with some of it's views toggling visibility based on other factors such as first-time on screen etc.

Comment: I posted this as a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71125440/stopping-all-exoplayers-in-items-of-a-non-scrolling-recyclerview-inside-a-nested)